# java: jakarta.inject.Provider.get() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface

Tags: java, weld

I am trying to use [dependency injection](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/part5.html#_bootstrapping_cdi_se) within my Java (SE) FX application but I am getting the error `java: jakarta.inject.Provider.get() is defined in an inaccessible class or interface` when using the following code.

```
@Log4j2
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        try (WeldContainer container = weld.initialize()) {
            container.select(MainWindowLoader.class).get().loadMainWindow(primaryStage);
        }
    }
}
```

The MainWindowLoader class looks as follows.

```
public class MainWindowLoader {
  public void loadMainWindow(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/MainWindow.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);

    final ObservableList<String> stylesheets = scene.getStylesheets();
    stylesheets.addAll(getClass().getResource("/css/style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setTitle("Avengers Manager");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

I am using following dependencies.

```
<!-- weld for dependency injection -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.SP1</version>
</dependency>
```

My one and only `module-info.java` files looks like this.

```
module avengers-manager {

  requires weld.se.core;
  requires weld.environment.common;
  requires weld.core.impl;
  requires jakarta.inject;

  opens us.tony.stark.avengers-manager;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to use the shaded dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.SP1</version>
</dependency>
```